# How make a attribute in interface required only when other attribute is true?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

How make a relative required (only make required when other attribute is true)?

Example:

```
interface ITesteProps {
  required: boolean
  content{!required && '?'}: string
}
```

I know it's not a valid code.
How make the content required only when the required === true?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like that:

```
type ITesteProps = { requred: true; content: string; } | {required: false; }
```

Comment: tks alot my friend